# css left or right set to 0 depending on box border

Tags: css, html

I have the next fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/76s7jn4q/2/

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1">
    <div class="box1">
      super long text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
    <div class="box2">
      super long text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to make text in the `<div class="box">` to be visible, placed on 1 line and align left or right to the `<div class="inner">` border depending on it place (right or left) to the `<div class="outer">` border. I have it done with box1 right: 0 but I need it to be automatic

Comment: did you try `margin: auto ;`

Comment: @MiladM on which element?

Comment: for `box1` and `box2` classes

Comment: @MiladM 
it does not help, in that case text overflows out of the outer div

Comment: remove `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: @MiladM In that case text would not be on the 1 line

Answer (score 1):

Alternative you can use this:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

All you need to position item/block or whatever order you want could be done using flexbox, and you get a much better responsive design. Easy to maintain and update. Read more here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.outer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner1 {
  position: relative;
 width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.inner2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
 text-align: right;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1">
    <div class="box1">
      super long text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
    <div class="box2">
      super long text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need text to be on 1 line

Comment: @ВадикОрлов to be honest, use flex you can achieve the same effect with much less code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is very simple, you only need to set the `overflow` to be `hidden` for the PARENT element, i.e. inner1 and inner2

https://jsfiddle.net/76s7jn4q/8/

Comment: it does not help, in that case text overflows out of the outer div

Comment: @ВадикОрлов "make div with the class box to align automatically to left or right depending on the outer box border". What do you mean by that?

Comment: I want text in box 1 to not overflow out of outer div, but without right: 0

Comment: @ВадикОрлов Do you mean sth like this? https://jsfiddle.net/76s7jn4q/7/

Comment: @ВадикОрлов you have a nowrap, your text will overflow because you have a fixed width of 80px. you can't fit 100px inside 80px

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy I have it working as I need, but I need box1 right set to 0; I want it to be set automatically if inner box is on the left or right side of the outer box

Comment: @ВадикОрлов I think that is what you need, answer is edited

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy ok)) I need all text to be visible and placed on 1 line and do not overflow outerdiv

Comment: @ВадикОрлов This is impossible. Don't you think it is contradiction? Place everything to be in 1 line, all text to be visible, but the width is limited and cannot have overflow. Physically it is impossible

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy I have done it with right set to 0 on the box1, but I need it to be automatic

Comment: @ВадикОрлов What do you mean by automatic? It is **already** automatic

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy if inner div is on the right side, then right: 0, if on the left side - left: 0 by default

Comment: @ВадикОрлов Why would you need that? Typing 8 more words is difficult for you?